# Quadratic Euler sums $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^{n-1} \widetilde H(n)^3}{2 n+1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form, harmonic-numbers, euler-sums

I'm computing a class of harmonic sums. Denote

- $H(n)=\sum_1^n \frac{1}{k}, \widetilde H(n)=\sum_1^n \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}$

Harmonic numbers, then how to prove

- $\small\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^{n-1} \widetilde H(n)^2 H(n)}{2 n+1}=\frac{\pi ^2 C}{12}-40 \Im(\text{Li}_4(1+i))+\frac{11}{12} \pi  \log ^3(2)+\frac{11}{16} \pi ^3 \log (2)+\frac{5 \psi ^{(3)}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)}{256}-\frac{5 \psi ^{(3)}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)}{256}$
- $\small \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^{n-1}\widetilde H(n) H(n)^2}{2 n+1}=\frac{\pi ^2 C}{6}+64 \Im(\text{Li}_4(1+i))-\frac{1}{3} 5 \pi  \log ^3(2)-\frac{9}{8} \pi ^3 \log (2)-\frac{\psi ^{(3)}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)}{32}+\frac{\psi ^{(3)}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)}{32}$
- $\small \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^{n-1} \widetilde H(n)^3}{2 n+1}=\frac{\pi ^2 C}{6}+24 \Im(\text{Li}_4(1+i))-\frac{1}{2} \pi  \log ^3(2)-\frac{3}{8} \pi ^3 \log (2)-\frac{5 \psi ^{(3)}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)}{384}+\frac{5 \psi ^{(3)}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)}{384}$

I'd like you to help me establish any of the 3 identities. Any help will be appreciated!

---

Appendix: To 'guess' the closed-form, use

```
S = {Pi^3 Log[2], Pi Log[2]^3, Pi^2*Catalan, Catalan*Log[2]^2, 
Pi*Zeta[3], Log[2] Im[PolyLog[3, 1 + I]], Im[PolyLog[4, 1 + I]], 
PolyGamma[3, 1/4] - PolyGamma[3, 3/4]};
S0 = {0, Pi^3 Log[2], Pi Log[2]^3, Pi^2*Catalan, Catalan*Log[2]^2, 
Pi*Zeta[3], Log[2] Im[PolyLog[3, 1 + I]], Im[PolyLog[4, 1 + I]], 
PolyGamma[3, 1/4] - PolyGamma[3, 3/4]};
TS = FindIntegerNullVector[
N[{'Numeric value of the sum', 
Pi^3 Log[2], Pi Log[2]^3, Pi^2*Catalan, Catalan*Log[2]^2, 
Pi*Zeta[3], Log[2] Im[PolyLog[3, 1 + I]], Im[PolyLog[4, 1 + I]], 
PolyGamma[3, 1/4] - PolyGamma[3, 3/4]}, 50]];
Expand[TS.S0/(-TS[[1]])]
```

---

Update: See arXiv $2007.03957$ for @pisco's solution on these series, evaluating a large class of polylog integrals including the one @Dr. Wolfgang Hintze's offered.

Comment: Very nice questions (+1). Do you have the integral representation of any?

Comment: Please see my answer giving an integral representation for the second sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering part of the question of @Ali Shather in a comment I have derived an integral representation for the second sum.

**Result**

We write

$$s_2 = \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^{n-1}\widetilde H(n) H(n)^2}{2 n+1} = \int_0^1 i_2(u) \,du\tag{1}$$

with the integrand

$$i_2(u) = \sum _{n=1}^{\infty }(-1)^{n-1}u^{2 n}\widetilde H(n) H(n)^2\tag{2}$$

Notice that the denominator $2n+1$ is generated by the integration over $u$.

I have calculated the sum in $(2)$ with a the following result which is composed of $\text{Li}_3$, $\text{Li}_2$, $\zeta(3)$ and $\log$s,

$$i_{2}(u)= -\frac{1}{24 \left(u^2+1\right)}\left(-24 \text{Li}_3\left(1-u^2\right)+6 \text{Li}_3\left(\left(\frac{1-u^2}{u^2+1}\right)^2\right)-24 \text{Li}_3\left(\frac{1}{u^2+1}\right)+24 \text{Li}_3\left(\frac{u^2}{u^2+1}\right)-24 \text{Li}_3\left(\frac{2 u^2}{u^2+1}\right)+24 \text{Li}_3\left(\frac{1}{2} \left(u^2+1\right)\right)+24 \log (2) \text{Li}_2\left(1-u^2\right)+24 \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{u^2+1}\right) \log \left(\frac{2}{u^2}+2\right)-24 \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{u^2}{u^2+1}\right) \log \left(\frac{u^2}{u^2+1}\right)+24 \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{2 u^2}{u^2+1}\right) \log \left(\frac{2 u^2}{u^2+1}\right)-24 \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1-u^2}{u^2+1}\right) \log \left(\frac{1}{u^2}-u^2\right)-24 \text{Li}_2\left(-\frac{1-u^2}{u^2+1}\right) \log \left(\frac{1-u^2}{u^2+1}\right)+24 \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{2} \left(u^2+1\right)\right) \log \left(\frac{2}{u^2+1}\right)+8 \log ^3\left(u^2+1\right)+60 \log (2) \log ^2\left(u^2+1\right)+8 \log ^2(2) \left(\log (2)-3 \log \left(u^2+1\right)\right)+8 \log \left(1-u^2\right) \left(-6 \left(\log \left(1-u^2\right)+2 \log \left(\frac{1}{2} \left(u^2+1\right)\right)\right) \log (u)+\log \left(1-u^2\right) \left(\log \left(\frac{1}{8} \left(1-u^2\right)\right)+3 \log \left(u^2+1\right)\right)+12 \log ^2(u)\right)-96 \log (2) \log (u) \log \left(u^2+1\right)-4 \pi ^2 \log \left(\frac{4}{1-u^2}\right)+21 \zeta (3)\right)\tag{3}$$

The corresponding Mathematica expression is provided in the appendix.

For a first check, the numeric evaluation of the integral gives with WorkingPrecision 30:

$$N(s_2) \simeq 0.9497576952344695293296230|77234\tag{4}$$

@metamorphory claimed to have calculated many more digits

$$0.9497576952344695293296230|8973659924...\tag{5}$$

Before the $"|"$ both values conincide. I take this as a strong ndication that my expression for $s_2$ is correct.

**Derivation**

In order to calculate the sum in $(2)$ we have several choices for the harmonic numbers involved. I found it useful to leave one factor $H_n$ as is and replace the other two be their integral representations

$$H_n \to  \int_0^1 \frac{1-x^n}{1-x}\tag{6a}$$

$$\widetilde H(n) \to \int_0^1 \frac{1-(-y)^n}{1+y}\tag{6b}$$

The sum in $(5)$ can then be done resulting in the following double integral for the integrand

$$i(u) = \int_{[0,1]^2} \left(\frac{\log \left(u^2+1\right)}{\left(u^2+1\right) (x+1) (1-y)}+\frac{\log \left(1-u^2 x\right)}{(x+1) (1-y) \left(u^2 x-1\right)}-\frac{\log \left(u^2 y+1\right)}{(x+1) (1-y) \left(u^2 y+1\right)}-\frac{\log \left(1-u^2 x y\right)}{(x+1) (1-y) \left(u^2 x y-1\right)}\right)\,dx\,dy\tag{7}$$

It turned out that it is convernient to take the $y$-integral first, for which Mathematica gives luckily directly (without the intermedaiate step of finding an antidrivative) this expression

$$i_y(u,x)=\frac{1}{6 \left(u^2+1\right) (x+1) \left(u^2 x-1\right)}\left(\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{u^2+1}\right) \left(6-6 u^2 x\right)+6 \left(u^2+1\right) \text{Li}_2\left(1-u^2 x\right)+\pi ^2 \left(u^2 (x-1)-2\right)+\left(9-9 u^2 x\right) \log ^2\left(u^2+1\right)+12 \left(u^2 x-1\right) \log (u) \log \left(u^2+1\right)+6 \left(u^2+1\right) \log \left(\frac{u^2 x}{1-u^2 x}\right) \log \left(1-u^2 x\right)\right)$$

For the final $x$-integral Mathematica (again directly) gives a long expression containing several complex terms, some explicit (factor i in front), others implicit (polylogs and logs with arguments outside the range leading to real expressions).

A careful analysis guided by the aim to make all terms real quatities using transformation formulas of polylogs leads to a lot of cancellations of complex terms and in the end leaves for the complex part of $i(u)$ this expression with a factor $i$ in front

$$z=-12 \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{u^2+1}\right)+12 \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1-u^2}{u^2+1}\right)-12 \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{u^2-1}{u^2+1}\right)+12 \text{Li}_2\left(1-\frac{1}{u^2}\right)-6 \log ^2\left(u^2+1\right)+24 \log (u) \log \left(\frac{u^2}{u^2+1}\right)+24 \log (u) \log \left(u^2+1\right)-24 \log ^2(u)+\pi ^2-12 \log ^2(2)+\log (4096) \log (2)$$

This, however, is numerically zero, and it is also simplified to exactly zero.

The rest of $i$ is the expression $i_2$ given in $(2)$ which contains only real terms.

This ends the derivation.

**Discussion**

Trying the final $u$-integration we encounter several non-trivial integrals.

One of the simpler ones is

$$\int_0^1 \frac{\log (u) \log (1-u)}{u^2+1} \, du=-\Im\left(\text{Li}_3\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i}{2}\right)\right)-\frac{\pi ^3}{128}-\frac{1}{32} \pi  \log ^2(2)$$

To do the $u$-integral completely and hereby confirm the closed form provided in the OP seems to require a huge amount of calculations.

Maybe the integrand can be significantly simplified which might facilitate the integration.

Facing the difficulties it is gratifying that the closed form was found by @Edit profile and settings using experimental mathematics and based on the high precision numerics provided by @metamorphy.

**Appendix**

The Mathematica expression of the integrand is

```
i2 = -(1/(
   24 (1 + u^2))) (-4 \[Pi]^2 Log[-(4/(-1 + u^2))] + 
    8 Log[2]^2 (Log[2] - 3 Log[1 + u^2]) - 
    96 Log[2] Log[u] Log[1 + u^2] + 60 Log[2] Log[1 + u^2]^2 + 
    8 Log[1 + u^2]^3 + 
    8 Log[1 - u^2] (12 Log[u]^2 - 
       6 Log[u] (Log[1 - u^2] + 2 Log[1/2 (1 + u^2)]) + 
       Log[1 - u^2] (Log[-(1/8) (-1 + u) (1 + u)] + 
          3 Log[1 + u^2])) + 24 Log[2] PolyLog[2, 1 - u^2] + 
    24 Log[2 + 2/u^2] PolyLog[2, 1/(1 + u^2)] - 
    24 Log[u^2/(1 + u^2)] PolyLog[2, u^2/(1 + u^2)] + 
    24 Log[(2 u^2)/(1 + u^2)] PolyLog[2, (2 u^2)/(1 + u^2)] + 
    24 Log[2/(1 + u^2)] PolyLog[2, 1/2 (1 + u^2)] - 
    24 Log[-1 + 2/(1 + u^2)] PolyLog[2, 1 - 2/(1 + u^2)] - 
    24 Log[1/u^2 - u^2] PolyLog[2, -1 + 2/(1 + u^2)] - 
    24 PolyLog[3, 1 - u^2] - 24 PolyLog[3, 1/(1 + u^2)] + 
    24 PolyLog[3, u^2/(1 + u^2)] - 24 PolyLog[3, (2 u^2)/(1 + u^2)] + 
    24 PolyLog[3, 1/2 (1 + u^2)] + 
    6 PolyLog[3, (1 - 2/(1 + u^2))^2] + 21 Zeta[3])
```

Comment: Great transformation (+1).

Comment: Thanks, Ali. It seems to work as well for the other two sums, but to work it out would be a somewhat tedious task.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a high-precision computation using [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/).

Since $\widetilde H(n)$ oscillates around $\log 2$, we use $\widetilde H(n)=\log 2+(-1)^{n-1}G(n)$ and interpolate $$H(n)=\gamma+\psi(n+1),\qquad G(n)=\frac12\left[\psi\left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right)-\psi\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)\right]$$ for numerical summation algorithms to work. Now the following script:

```
\p110
hoo(x)=Euler+psi(x+1);
goo(x)=(psi(x/2+1)-psi((x+1)/2))/2;
posfoo(a,b)=sumnum(n=1,hoo(n)^a*goo(n)^b/(2*n+1));
altfoo(a,b)=sumalt(n=1,(-1)^(n-1)*hoo(n)^a*goo(n)^b/(2*n+1));
foo(a,b)=if(b%2,posfoo(a,b),altfoo(a,b));
foo(1,2)+log(2)*(2*foo(1,1)+log(2)*foo(1,0))
foo(2,1)+log(2)*foo(2,0)
foo(0,3)+log(2)*(3*foo(0,2)+log(2)*(3*foo(0,1)+log(2)*foo(0,0)))
```

produces

```
0.63485270692567176439762481050085614868116091742894598008616894909585914099639885258809006289267577990028173580
0.94975769523446952932962308973659924330156320890881194425081913257798444110597633613478205511449762298041395829
0.45817132254283026944102875255795848604967226439415055431132352007951855933151094926509535191523963750882074225
```